# Is converting an ambiguous grammar to an unambiguous grammar computable?

Tags: computability, context-free, formal-grammars, undecidability

Is the problem of converting ambiguous grammar into unambiguous grammar computable? (Consider Domain as all context free languages).

Comment: Are you asking whether it is decidable to check whether a given context-free grammar generates an inherently ambiguous language? If so, then the answer is no: it is undecidable. See this answer: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19116/40.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I am asking for whether is there any Halting Turing machine available for converting an ambiguous grammar into an unambiguous grammar. If yes then the problem of converting an ambiguous grammar into an unambiguous grammar is computable (or decidable).

Comment: Note that [deciding ambiguity is not computable](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/how-is-proving-a-context-free-language-to-be-ambiguous-undecidable) so chances are slim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that question is about derivation, otherwise the outcome does not change, but please read Yuval's comment for further details.

No it is not computable in the domain of your choice. There are inherently ambigous grammars, which are subset of context-free grammars. For the subset without inherently ambigous ones it is computable.

I like to point to [thesis about ambiguous grammars](http://digital.library.okstate.edu/etd/umi-okstate-1373.pdf), which is consistent with what I wrote, contains the same proof as [TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19116/40) topic.

Since the problem of finding out whether grammar is inherently ambiguous is undecidable then you cannot build halting Turing Machine for such task. And yes, if you could built one it would be decidable.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct - how do you construct an equivalent unambiguous grammar, given that one exists?

Comment: Seconded. [Deciding ambiguity is not computable](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/how-is-proving-a-context-free-language-to-be-ambiguous-undecidable) so this should be interesting.