# Does transforming a CFG to Chomsky normal form make it unambiguous?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Does transforming a CFG to Chomsky normal form make it unambiguous?
And if not, is there a technique to convert a CFG G to an equivalent CFG G', so that G' is both unambiguous and LL(1)?

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60246/98).

Comment: An LL(1) grammar is necessarily unambiguous (by definition) but there are unambiguous languages which do not have LL(1) grammars.

Answer (score 10):

There are inherently ambiguous context-free languages, and like all context-free languages they have grammars in Chomsky normal form, so transforming a CFG to Chomsky normal form doesn't necessarily make it unambiguous. For the same reason there is no technique to convert an arbitrary context-free grammar to one which in unambiguous.

Deciding whether a given context-free grammar is ambiguous, or whether a given context-free grammar generates an inherently ambiguous language, is undecidable. This doesn't necessarily mean that there is no procedure that converts any context-free grammar into an unambiguous one given that the language isn't inherently unambiguous, but it does make the existence of such an algorithm somewhat doubtful.

Comment: What algorithms are there (if they exist) for finding unambiguous versions of restricted forms of CFGs? Of course, it would have to be not a DCFL (since they always have unambiguous grammars).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert in the area.